# Unable to Use functx library with intellij idea community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, xquery, marklogic, functx

I am trying to import **functx** library using following import statement but i am not able to import it to my `.xqy` file in intellij idea community edition - 2018.1

```
    xquery version "1.0-ml";
    import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";

    functx:get-matches(
       'abc123def', '[a-z]{2}')
```

I am getting this error saying - **cannot resolve function 'functx:get-matches'**

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to resolve the functx library module you need to add the path to the Modules directory of your MarkLogic installation to your project.

- Go to File -> Project Structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
- Select *Modules*
- Click *+ Add Content Root*
- Browse to your MarkLogic installation and select the Modules directory (i.e. `C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules`)

Now, it should resolve the methods, allow you to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> click to jump to the function in the functx module, and will provide auto-completion for functx functions as you type.

Comment: Thx @Mads Hansen... Now it  is Working and I am getting auto-completion as well  but after adding Modules to Project Structure when i click Apply and Ok I am getting Error Msg saying "Unable to save settings: Failed to save settings. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA"